# Passing SELECT Option's value and text to tags input on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a simple multi-user messaging system. There are many kinds of users and user categories on the system so I have multiple `<select>` inputs from which they can select the user and then add it to the `recipient` input, which is a tags input.

I then want to pass the users id's to a PHP function using AJAX. I figured out how to add the ids to the `recipients` input field, but I want the user to see the usernames and not their ids, but I want to pass the ids. Also, when the user removes a user from the `recipients` input field (delete tag), I want the id of that user to also be removed.

How can I achieve this handling `input tags` by passing the ID but displaying the selected text? I know how to display the text of the selected item in input tags, but how can I only pass the IDs? Also how do i handle deletion of a tag with the username, and also delete the relevant id?

Stripped down version of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <select id="userlist1" class="form-control">
        <option value="none" selected="" disabled="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">John</option>
        <option value="2">Sarah</option>
        <option value="3">Bob</option>
    </select>
    <button id="btnaddfromuserlist1"> Add to Reciepients List</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <select id="userlist2" class="form-control">
        <option value="none" selected="" disabled="">Select</option>
        <option value="8">Richard</option>
        <option value="9">Hazel</option>
        <option value="10">Adam</option>
    </select>
    <button id="btnaddfromuserlist2"> Add to Reciepients List</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" id="reciepients" >
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#btnaddfromuserlist1").click(function(){
    var userid= $("#userlist1").val();
    $('#reciepients').tagsinput('add', userid);
});

$("#btnaddfromuserlist2").click(function(){
    var userid= $("#userlist2").val();
    $('#reciepients').tagsinput('add', userid);
});
```

Comment: `var username= $("#userlist1 option:selected").text();`

Comment: But how can I handle multiple recipients?